# NLP parsing multiple questions contained in one single query

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, chatbot

If a single query from the user contains multiple questions belonging to different categories, how can they be identified, split and parsed?

Eg -

```
User - what is the weather now and tell me my next meeting  
Parser - {:weather => "what is the weather", :schedule => "tell me my next meeting"}
```

*Parser identifies the parts of sentences where the question belongs to two different categories*

```
User - show me hotels in san francisco for tomorrow that are less than $300 but not less than $200 are pet friendly have a gym and a pool with 3 or 4 stars staying for 2 nights and dont include anything that doesnt have wifi  
Parser - {:hotels => ["show me hotels in san francisco",  
          "for tomorrow", "less than $300 but not less than $200",
          "pet friendly have a gym and a pool",
          "with 3 or 4 stars", "staying for 2 nights", "with wifi"]}
```

*Parser identifies the question belonging to only one category but has additional steps for fine tuning the answer and created an array ordered according to the steps to take*

From what I can understand this requires a **sentence segmenter**, **multi-label classifier** and **co-reference resolution**

But the *sentence segementer* I have come across depend heavily on grammar, punctuations.

*Multi-label classifiers*, like a good trained naive bayes classifier works in most cases but since they are multi-label, most times output multiple categories for sentences which clearly belong to one class. Depending solely on the array outputs to check the labels present would fail.

If used a multi-class classifier, that is also good to check the array output of probable categories but obviously they dont tell the different parts of the sentence much accurately, much less in what fashion to proceed with the next step.

**As a first step, how can I tune sentence segmenter to correctly split the sentence without any strict grammar rules.** Good accuracy of this would help a lot in classification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As a first step, how can I tune sentence segmenter to correctly split the sentence without any strict grammar rules.

Instead of doing this I'd suggest you use the parse-tree directly (either dependency parser, or constituency parse).

Here I'm showing the output of the dependency parse and you can see that the two segments are separated via a "CONJ" arrow:

[image]

(from here: http://deagol.cs.illinois.edu:8080/)

Another solution I'd give try is ClausIE: 
https://gate.d5.mpi-inf.mpg.de/ClausIEGate/ClausIEGate?inputtext=what+is+the+weather+now+and+tell+me+my+next+meeting++&processCcAllVerbs=true&processCcNonVerbs=true&type=true&go=Extract

Comment: Yes this method helps. For the hotels sentence however, it would become difficult. That is for sentences where the program does not yet know if the query contains two or more labels. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you give examples? I need to get a better sense of what you saying ...

Comment: To be clear, for the 1st query, which you gave the demo, it is very helpful to look at the dependency tree to find if there are multiple queries. But for the 2nd query, hotel example, we can just extract noun phrases, after parser is sure that the query has **only one label**. So question is, what other things to look for in the graph to be certain that the question has 1 or many queries. In clausie - for 1st query - **conj** appears directly under root, so parser can tell there is possibly 2nd label, but also in the hotel example, **conj** also appears the same way. How to deal with that?

Comment: Look at this dependency extraction for **conj** - https://gate.d5.mpi-inf.mpg.de/ClausIEGate/ClausIEGate?inputtext=show+me+hotels+in+san+francisco+for+tomorrow+that+are+less+than+%24300+but+not+less+than+%24200+are+pet+friendly+have+a+gym+and+a+pool+with+3+or+4+stars+staying+for+2+nights+and+dont+include+anything+that+doesnt+have+wifi&processCcAllVerbs=true&processCcNonVerbs=true&type=true&go=Extract

Comment: This example has no conjunction indicator but there are two statements but not an apparent way to find an answer- https://gate.d5.mpi-inf.mpg.de/ClausIEGate/ClausIEGate?inputtext=find+me+an+italian+restaurant+in+new+york+city+also+whats+the+weather+there+tomorrow&processCcAllVerbs=true&processCcNonVerbs=true&type=true&go=Extract -

Answer (score 2):

If you want something for **segmentation** that doesn't depend on grammar heavily, then **chunking** comes to mind. In the NLTK book there is [a fragment on that](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html#chunking_index_term). The approach authors take here depends only on part of speech tags.

BTW Jurafsky and Martin's 3rd ed of [Speech and Language processing](https://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/slp3/) contains information on chunking in the parsing chapter, and it also contains a chapters on information retrieval nad chatbots.

Comment: Noun phrase chunking would only club certain phrases though. Are you suggesting to run them through a classifier to see if it is part of a the same category or different category? I think this would require a new training to determine how the parser is supposed to decide how to process chunks.

Comment: You asked for something for segmentation. I was suggesting this as a step to find out which parts can be potentially used as proper questions.